# PHP <select> <option> showing selected <option> twice

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem where the `<option selected>` showing twice.
I am populating the `<select><option>` with data from **titles** table 
I want to show selected option based on data from **taos** table.

The data output is shown as:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7V4E.png
and
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBFPh.png

```
<?php

$title_sql = "SELECT * FROM titles";
echo "<select class='form-control' name='title_id'>";

 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $title_sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

   $dbselected = $tao['title_id'];

    foreach ($row as $option) {
     if ($dbselected == $option) {
?>
     <option selected value='$row[id]'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
<?php
     } else {

     }
   }
   echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[title]</option>";
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

```html
<?php

    $title_sql = "SELECT * FROM titles";
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='title_id'>";
    
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $title_sql)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    
       $dbselected = $tao['title_id'];
    
        foreach ($row as $option) {
           if ($dbselected == $option) {    
?>
             <option selected value='$row[id]'>
                 <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
             </option>
           <?php
           } else {
    
           }
        }
           echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[title]</option>";
      }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why have you posted links to images of HTML text? Its just UTF8 data.

Comment: The links to the images are the output to the DOM. 
I thought it would help better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the `foreach` section you left `else` section empty, and show your all select values outside the condition

try this

```
<?php

$title_sql = "SELECT * FROM titles";
echo "<select class='form-control' name='title_id'>";

 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $title_sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

   $dbselected = $tao['title_id'];

    foreach ($row as $option) {
     if ($dbselected == $option) {
?>
     <option selected value='$row[id]'><?php echo $row['title']; ?></option>
<?php
     } else {
       echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[title]</option>";
     }
   }
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Comment: This is the results

1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83HfQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yapGN.png

Comment: @ACMethod can you show what you get in `$row` after that request `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [status] => Red
    [description] => Action with immediate affect
)

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is outputting the `option` with `selected` when it is equal to the `$dbselected` value. Then you are outputting the option (without `selected`) unconditionally. Move the last `echo` into the `else {` portion of that `if` to prevent it from being output if you have already outputted with `selected`

Also, you do not want the `foreach ($row as $option) {`; as that is walking through the columns of the row, so the second `echo` will be repeated for each column.

Also, be consistent. Either use `echo` or drop out of PHP; don't do it one way and then the other.

Try it this way:

```
 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $title_sql)) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

   $dbselected = $tao['title_id'];

   ## foreach ($row as $option) { ## TAKE THIS OUT
     if ($dbselected == $option) {
?>
       echo "<option selected value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['title']}</option>";
<?php
     } else {
       echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['title']}</option>"; ## MOVED FROM BELOW
     }
   ## } ## (End of foreach) TAKE THIS OUT 
   ## echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[title]</option>"; ## MOVED THIS UP
  }
```

I would actually use [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) instead of the `if-else`:

```
printf('<OPTION %s value="%s">%s</OPTION>',
    ($dbselected == $row['id'] ? "selected" : ""),
    $row['id'], 
    htmlspecialchars($row['title']));
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining.
It's still not working.
I am now just getting the list, not the selected based on dbselected

Comment: I would try the printF but i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question to show you how better formatting makes it easier to find your problem.  your third echo statement is being executed first,  It is outside your else block and should be inside it

```html
<?php

    $title_sql = "SELECT * FROM titles";
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='title_id'>";
    
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $title_sql)) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    
       $dbselected = $tao['title_id'];
    
        foreach ($row as $option) {
           if ($dbselected == $option) {    
?>
             <option selected value='$row[id]'>
                 <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
             </option>
           <?php
           } else {
    
           }
        }
           echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[title]</option>";
      }
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    echo "</select>"; ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this, 
when the third echo is placed inside the else block it is showing each row twice.
Confusing the hell out me. :P

Comment: can you show us what is in $result?  Oh I just caught this, your if statement should be == not =  also your while statement should be ==  and what does this do mysqli_free_result($result);

Answer (score 0):

Look no further `<select><option>` from database showing selected option if found in another table

Select an option

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM titles";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$selected = $resident['title_id'];
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
mysqli_free_result($result);
?>

 <?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
  <?php if ($selected == $row['id']) { ?>
   <option selected value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> 
   <?php echo $row['status']; ?></option>
   <?php } else { ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <?php } ?>
 <?php echo $row['status']; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```